# Better way of validating RadioBoxes with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

i have a couple of radio button groups on my webpage, and this how i decided to validate the groups

```
function validateAppRXForm() {
    if($('input[name="creativity"]:checked').length == 0 ||
    $('input[name="intelligence"]:checked').length == 0 ||
    $('input[name="initiative"]:checked').length == 0 ||
    $('input[name="motivation"]:checked').length == 0 ||
    $('input[name="development"]:checked').length == 0 ||
    $('input[name="vision"]:checked').length == 0 ||
    $('input[name="Integrity"]:checked').length == 0 ||
    $('input[name="Confidentiality"]:checked').length == 0 ||
    $('input[name="Interpersonal"]:checked').length == 0 ||
    $('input[name="speed"]:checked').length == 0 ||
    $('input[name="accuracy"]:checked').length == 0 ||
    $('input[name="ability"]:checked').length == 0 ||
    $('input[name="assessmnt"]:checked').length == 0 ||
    $('input[name="errors"]:checked').length == 0){
       alert('some fields were left blank..');
       // alert('some fields were left blank...');
       return false;
    }
 }
```

but i feel there can be a better way where i pass the names from an array.. so i decided to do this using the names of the radio buttons

```
 //create the array by splitting string names.... 
 let arr = String('creativity;intelligence;initiative;motivation;development;vision;Integrity;Confidentiality;Interpersonal;speed;$accuracy;ability;assessmnt;errors').split(';');

//loop through and validate...
function validateAppRXForm() {
   arr.forEach(name => {
      if($('input[name=`${name}`"]:checked').length == 0){
         alert('some fields were left blank..');
         return false;
      }
   });
}
```

but its not working...

Comment: @mplungjan it still works, i just prefer casting it ...

Comment: Note a  `return` in `forEach` does not return to the outer function. Using `some()` woud be a cleaner approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this, although I recommend to not use unchecked radios but selects instead if you want to test none/a/b selections

```js
//create the array by splitting string names.... 
let arr = 'creativity;intelligence;initiative'.split(';');
$(function() {
  $("form").on("submit", function(e) {
    if (arr.filter(item => $(`input[name=${item}]:checked`).length === 0).length > 0) {
      console.log("some rads not checked");
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  Creativity:
  <label><input type="radio" name="creativity" value="yes" />Yes</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="creativity" value="no" />No</label>
  <br/> Intelligence:
  <label><input type="radio" name="intelligence" value="yes" />Yes</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="intelligence" value="no" />No</label>
  <br/> Initiative:
  <label><input type="radio" name="initiative" value="yes" />Yes</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="initiative" value="no" />No</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array#every()` with `is(':checked')` as a shorter way to write it than checking length

```js
//create the array by splitting string names.... 
let arr = 'creativity;intelligence;initiative'.split(';');

function isValid(){
  return arr.every(name => $(`input[name='${name}']`).is(':checked'))
}

console.log('On load:', isValid())

// check one of each
arr.forEach(name => $(`input[name='${name}']`).first().prop('checked', true))
console.log('After checked:', isValid())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  Creativity:
  <label><input type="radio" name="creativity" value="yes" />Yes</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="creativity" value="no" />No</label>
  <br/> Intelligence:
  <label><input type="radio" name="intelligence" value="yes" />Yes</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="intelligence" value="no" />No</label>
  <br/> Initiative:
  <label><input type="radio" name="initiative" value="yes" />Yes</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="initiative" value="no" />No</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Nice one....... You are not validating on submit but still nice